# PowerBi Line Chart Toggle

Tags: powerbi

I am making a multi-line chart in Power BI, and I want to turn each line on/off depending on slicer selection.

I tried a measure that gets 0 or 1 depending on slicer selection, but I can't use that value to plot/remove a specific line.

I also created a calculated column based on the selection, but it won't recognize the user selection.

[Chart]